Frontend not able to communicate with backend in GKE
enter image description here
I have to service frontend and backend , i created their docker file and push Google Artifact Registry ,  i deployed both the services in a GKE Cluster
Node Servide.yaml


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-node-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-node-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-node-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-node-server
        image: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/ycxz-426410/ycxz/backend:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-node-server-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-node-server
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
  type: ClusterIP 

Frontend.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-react-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-react-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-react-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-react-server
        image: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/ycxz-426410/ycxz/frontend:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
          - name: REACT_APP_URL
            value: "http://my-node-server-service.default.svc.cluster.local"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-react-server-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-react-server
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  type: ClusterIP

and my ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-react-server-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          
  ingressClassName: nginx 

after apllying these file my react server got up and access it using ingress external ip
but it showing error that it not able communicate with backend
Backend URL: http://my-node-server-service.default.svc.cluster.local
App.js:23 Backend URL: http://my-node-server-service.default.svc.cluster.local
App.js:15 Fetching message...
App.js:15 Fetching message...
App.js:20 Error fetching message: AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
fetchMessage @ App.js:20
await in fetchMessage (async)
(anonymous) @ App.js:10
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23189
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24965
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24930
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24917
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24905
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27078
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:27023
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26808
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 11 more frames
Show lessUnderstand this error
App.js:16 
        
        
 GET http://my-node-server-service.default.svc.cluster.local/api/hello net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED



how to dynamically make communication betwwen frontend and backend
when i login  to Kubernetes pod and try to to
curl http://my-node-server-service.default.svc.cluster.local/api/hello

it working but the outside cluster is not able to access

It sounds like the frontend is running in the end user's browser; that's outside the cluster and can't see the ...svc.cluster.local hostnames.  You need to set up an Ingress for the backend that the browser application can reach.

but in this way, I expose my backend to the outside world, I don't want to expose my APIs to the outside world is there any way to do

The end user's browser isn't running in the cluster.  If the API isn't exposed, how should the application reach it?
